# Retrieving tkinter Combobox value - bind not working

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, combobox

I'm struggling to retrieve the selected value of a tkinter `ComboBox`. I am wanting to have one thread assigned to running the GUI for a simple program I'm developing. On a separate thread I aim to have my "main" script and on another thread have a loop for controlling a couple of electric motors. I have some high resolution motor encoders that I will be using to track RPM & Position of the motors so having those loops on their own thread to avoid missing any encoder samples is ideal.

This is all hinged on my being able to send user inputs from my GUI thread to my "main" thread which will serve various purposes. I'm able to retrieve slider scale values with no issue but it seems as though the `ComboBox` bind event is never being triggered upon selection. From the research I've done, none of the examples I can find show a `ComboBox` bind event being triggered from outside a thread. I can only figure therein lies the problem? If so why do the slider scale commands function properly?

First code block is my "main" script.

```py
#############################
#### Importing Libraries ####
#############################

from GUI import*

class Round_Sling_Main:
    def sling_start(self):
        current_length = start.get_length()
        current_speed = start.get_speed()
        current_color = start.get_color()
        print(current_length, current_speed, current_color)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    round_sling = Round_Sling_Main()
    start = GUI(round_sling, 0,0,"")
```

Second block of code is my "GUI" creation thread. Points of interest here are Lines 32-33 & Lines 75 - 93. For retrieval of the SlingColor Combobox I have tried several different solutions that I have found online. Such as:

1. `SlingColor.bind("<<Combobox Selected>>", lambda: self.retrieve_color(SlingColor.get())`

- The thought here was to assign an attribute of `retrieve_color` the value `SlingColor.get()`
- This returns the initial value of the `ComboBox` `' '` but is never triggered when a selection is made.
- This would of course require re-defining the function retrieve_color.
- `def retrieve_color(self, color)`

2. The method shown in my linked code block does not seem to ever trigger the bound function.

```py
#############################
#### Importing Libraries ####
#############################

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import threading
import sys

############################
#### Creating GUI Class ####
############################

class GUI:

    t1_running = True

    def __init__(self, round_sling, length, speed, color):
        self.round_sling = round_sling
        self.length = length
        self.speed = speed
        self.color = color
        self.t1 = threading.Thread(target = self.create_GUI)
        self.t1.start()

    def retrieve_length(self, length):
        self.length = length

    def retrieve_speed(self, speed):
        self.speed = speed

    def retrieve_color(event = None):
        print(event.widget.get())

    def get_length(self):
        return self.length

    def get_speed(self):
        return self.speed

    def get_color(self):
        return self.color

    def close(self):
        self.t1_running = False
        sys.exit()

    def create_GUI(self):

        while self.t1_running:

            front = tk.Tk()
            front.title ("Round Sling Machine")
            front.geometry ('800x600')
            #front.config (cursor = 'none')
            #front.attributes ("-fullscreen", True)

            # Color Selection Label
            Color_Label = tk.Label (front, text = 'Select a Sling Color', font = 'Verdana 12')
            Color_Label.place(x = 300, y = 0)

            # Material Selection Label
            Material_Label = tk.Label (front, text = 'Select a Sling Material', font = 'Verdana 12')
            Material_Label.place(x = 300, y = 80)

            # Length Entry Label
            Length_Label = tk.Label (front, text = 'Select Desired Sling Length (inches)', font = 'Verdana 12')
            Length_Label.place(x = 240,y = 160)

            # Speed Factor Label
            Speed_Label = tk.Label (front, text = 'Enter Motor Speed Factor (0.0 - 1.0)', font = 'Verdana 8')
            Speed_Label.place(x = 25, y = 35)

            # Color Selection Combo Box
            ColorVar = tk.StringVar()
            SlingColor = ttk.Combobox(front, width = 27, textvariable = ColorVar)
            SlingColor['values'] = ('Purple',
                                    'Green',
                                    'Yellow',
                                    'Tan',
                                    'Red',
                                    'White',
                                    'Blue',
                                    'Orange 1',
                                    'Orange 2',
                                    'Orange 3',
                                    'Orange 4',
                                    'Orange 5',
                                    'Orange 6')
            SlingColor.state(["readonly"])
            SlingColor.place(x = 300, y = 30)

            SlingColor.bind("<<Combobox Selected>>", self.retrieve_color)

            # Material Selection Combo Box
            MaterialVar = tk.StringVar()
            MaterialSel = ttk.Combobox(front, width = 27, textvariable = MaterialVar)
            MaterialSel['values'] = ('Nylon', 'Polyester', 'Carbon Fiber')
            MaterialSel.state(["readonly"])
            MaterialSel.place(x = 300, y = 110)

            # Sling Length Slider
            SlingLength = tk.Scale(front, from_ = 0, to = 100, length = 600, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command = self.retrieve_length)
            SlingLength.place(x = 105, y = 190)

            # Motor Speed Factor Slider
            MotorSpeed = tk.Scale(front, from_ = 0, to = 1.0, resolution = 0.1, length = 200, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command = self.retrieve_speed)
            MotorSpeed.place(x = 25, y = 50)

            startBtn = tk.Button(front, text = 'Start', font = 'Verdana 12', command = self.round_sling.sling_start)
            startBtn.place(x = 250, y = 250)

            closeBtn = tk.Button(front, text = 'Close', font = 'Verdana 12', command = self.close)
            closeBtn.place(x = 450, y = 250)

            front.mainloop()
```

Comment: `retrieve_color()` should have two arguments: `self` and `event`. So it should be `def retrieve_color(self, event)`.

Comment: Also the event is `<<ComboboxSelected>>` instead of `<<Combobox Selected>>`.

Comment: Oh my gosh... that was the problem. I've been stuck on this for two weeks and it was a space causing my problem. I'm super new.. obviously haha